# Opening up jHipster spring-boot security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster

I want to open up spring security to "the world" during development. jHipster has a amazing generator but I am a little confused. How can I open spring security for restful calls with no issue?
[image]

```
/**
 * Authenticate a user from the database.
 */
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class DomainUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DomainUserDetailsService.class);

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public DomainUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
        log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);
        String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(lowercaseLogin);
        return userFromDatabase.map(user -> {
            if (!user.getActivated()) {
                throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
            }
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
                    .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(lowercaseLogin,
                user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities);
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the " +
        "database"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To permit anyone to access the REST API, change the following line in your SecurityConfiguration.java, located at `src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/config/SecurityConfiguration.java`

```
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```

to

```
        .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
```

You can then restrict specific API endpoints if you want with either of the following annotations:

```
        @Secured(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
```

or

```
        @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
```